# Time lag when collecting data and using datetime.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, delay

I'm trying to collect data of cotizations through an API each minute, and for this I have used a loop that pauses 60 seconds, actually all this works but I have some troubles.

For example, when I send a petition at the time `12:00`, it receives the data of the `11:59` but I want to receive the data of `12:00`.
This only happens when I use `time.sleep()` and the delay it is proportional to the seconds that I put inside of the `time.sleep()` function

This is my code:

```
from iqoptionapi.api import IQOptionAPI
from datetime import datetime
import time

candles = None
contador = 1
while True:
    if candles is None:
        api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "user", "pass") # Data for conection
        api.connect()
        api.getcandles(1,1) # (id_active, time)
        candles = api.candles.candles_data # List with candles
        print ("Try....\n")
    else:
        print ("Candle petition:", contador, "-", datetime.now(), "\n")
        api.getcandles(1, 1)
        candles = api.candles.candles_data
        print (candles, "\n")
        print ("First list:", datetime.fromtimestamp(candles[0][0]),
               "Second list:", datetime.fromtimestamp(candles[1][0]), "\n")
        contador += 1

    time.sleep(60)
```

and these are my results:

```
Candle petition: 2 - 2017-01-25 10:14:05.554242

[[1485360784, 1073590, 1073600, 1073600, 1073590], [1485360785,
1073600, 1073595, 1073600, 1073595]]

First list: 2017-01-25 10:13:04 Second list: 2017-01-25 10:13:05
```

What is happening? Why the delay?

Comment: The actual amount of time execution suspends due to `time.sleep()` suspension time may be less than that what is requested . You could do it more accurately by replacing the call with a loop that repeatedly called `datetime.now()` until at least the desired amount of time had passed (perhaps sleeping a fraction of a second between each call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [IQOptionAPI](https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi/blob/master/iqoptionapi/ws/client.py) uses [websocket-client](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client), which is asynchronous. Sending a request will return immediately, without waiting for a response from the server. You are checking for the response before you have received it. As a result, what you are getting is actually the result of the *previous* request. That's why it corresponds to the length of the `sleep` you use.

I don't immediately see a way within IQOptionAPI to make a synchronous request or get any sort of feedback when the response comes in, but it would be best to look a little closer and see if there is indeed a way. As a workaround, try inserting a couple of seconds of delay between the request and checking the response:

```
api.getcandles(1, 1)
time.sleep(2)
candles = api.candles.candles_data
```

Comment: Thanks this is the solution, now i receive the cotizations in real time without delay